# Ethers.js BigNumber calculation incorrect

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, pancakeswap, bignumber

I'm trying to replicate the PancakeswapV2 getAmountOut function in Javascript using ethers.BigNumbers as follows (the code in the comment is ad-verbatum from PancakeswapLibrary)

```
function getTokensOut(_amountIn, _reserve0, _reserve1) {
        /*
            getAmountOut
            uint amountInWithFee = amountIn.mul(998);
            uint numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(reserveOut);
            uint denominator = reserveIn.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee);
            amountOut = numerator / denominator;
        */
        const amountInWithFee = _amountIn.mul(ethers.BigNumber.from(998))
        const numerator = amountInWithFee.mul(_reserve1)
        const denominator = _reserve0.mul(1000).add(amountInWithFee)
        return numerator.div(denominator)
    }
}
```

For whatever reason, however, the values returned from the above function are quite a bit different from those returned from the Solidity code using the same input (or via Pancake Router, or using an "infinite" precision calculator [which btw, gives the same result as Solidity]

For instance:

```
_amountIn: 500000000000000000
_reserve0: 508182386709642941160
_reserve1: 138068946110314350251292627
```

Using the above function returns:

```
135441173805663861743470
```

but Solidity / Pancake Router / Infinite Precision Calculator all return

```
135373384037682332659863
```

What's the explanation for this, and more importantly, how does the above Javascript function need to be corrected for it to return the correct results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem: the Pancakeswap Library on github uses 998/1000 to calculate the fees, but the deployed contract uses 9975/10000. With this adjustment the function is working fine.